# Laravel 5.1 - mysql orderby the highest value of count distinct

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My main purpose is to show my best sellers products.

My table name is order_item with columns(id, cart_id, product_id, etc..)

Controller:

```
$orderitems = DB::table('order_items')
        ->select('product_id')->get();
```

Html:

```
<div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    @foreach($orderitems as $order)
        {{$order->product_id}}<br>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

the result of this foreach action is: 2, 6, 2, 4, 6, 6.

My purpose is to show results: 6,2,4. (We have three 6 so it might be the first, two 2 it might be going second and one 4 it might be going the last)
I want the highest count distict numbers to show first in this order.

I tryed in my controller the code:

```
$orderitems = DB::table('order_items')
        ->select('product_id')->orderBy(distict(count('product_id')));
```

but it fails with a message:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\distict()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how you should use the `distinct` method (and `orderBy`):

```
$orderitems = DB::table(DB::raw('(SELECT product_id, COUNT(*) as product_count FROM order_items GROUP BY product_id) AS subquery'))
    ->select('product_id')
    ->orderBy('product_count')
    ->get();
```

Comment: I have an error:

Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\wamp64\www\test3\resources\views\master\master.blade.php)

Comment: My bad... I just reedit my answer. I forgot abount `->get()`

Comment: Another error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function pluck() on array

Comment: Could you: dd($orderitems) <- should by a `Collection` not an array

Comment: It gives me array 3: ->

Comment: OK. I see now. In L5.1 the DB returns an array not a collection - it has changed in L5.2 I will update my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111744/discussion-between-vasilis-greece-and-filip-koblanski).